# Поиск цифр в строке. Python

Tags: python, строки, сортировка, поиск

Задание:

1. Вывести все четные цифры (без повторений), которые содержатся во всех словах и количество слов.
2. Найти и вывести в самом длинном слове все символы , отличные от заглавных латинских букв.

Код:

```
import string

text = input('Введите строку: ') # ввод символов с клавиатуры
print('Вы ввели: {}'.format(text)) 
words = text.split()
#найдем все четные цифры без повторений
mass = []
for elem in words:
    if elem % 2 == 0:
        mass.append(elem)
print('Цифры:', mass)
#подсчитаем количество слов
print('Количество слов: {}'.format(len(words)))
# найдем самое длинное слово
longest_word = max(words,key = len)
print('Самое длинное слово: {}'.format(longest_word))
# удаляем заглавные латинские буквы из самого длинного слова
for ch in longest_word:
    if ch in string.ascii_uppercase:
        longest_word = longest_word.replace(ch,'')
print('Самое длинное слово после удаления заглавных латинских букв: {}'.format(longest_word))
```

Проблема:

Выдает ошибку в 9 строке. В остальном работает. Не может найти цифры. Подскажите, как правильно считать строку поэлементно?

Comment: В чем заключается ошибка?

Comment: @demonplus Явно в том, что у строки нельзя получить остаток от деления на 2.

Answer (score 2):

Решение достаточно простое и ошибка, как указывалось в комментариях от того, что вы пытаетесь разделить по остатку переменную с типом данных `string`. Все что необходимо вам так это проверить: "Является, ли, элемент списка числом?". Для этого можно применить метод `isdisgit()`. Примерно будет выглядеть так:

```py
>>> text = "jdføso 780 hsafp9 934 7384 iukdf" # тестовая строка
>>> words = text.split()
>>> mass = set()
>>> for elem in words:
>>>     if elem.isdigit():
>>>         print(f"Какой же тип данных у {elem}. Ответ {type(elem)}") # посмотрим на тип данных здесь
>>>         if int(elem) % 2 == 0:
>>>            mass.add(elem)
>>> print('Цифры:', mass)
Какой же тип данных у 780. Ответ <class 'str'>
Какой же тип данных у 934. Ответ <class 'str'>
Какой же тип данных у 7384. Ответ <class 'str'>
Цифры: {'780', '934', '7384'}
```

`mass` - переменную я определил тип данных как `set`, что дает нам уникальные значения для конечного результата. Проверим:

```py
>>> text = "jdføso 780 hsafp9 934 7384 iukdf 934" # тестовая строка
...
...
>>> Цифры: {'934', '7384', '780'}
```

Это исправление вашего решения, но я вчитался еще раз в задание и понимаю, что вам надо найти все четные цифры, а не числа. В том числе и которые содержатся в словах. Можно решить вот так:

```py
>>> import re
>>> 
>>> text = "jdføso 780 hsafp9 934 7384 iukdf 934"
>>> mass = set()
>>> pattern = r"\d"
>>> all_digits = set(re.findall(pattern, text))
>>> for item in all_digits:
>>>     if int(item) % 2 == 0:
>>>         mass.add(item)
>>> print(f"Цифры: {mass}")
Цифры: {'8', '0', '4'}
```